# shared_ptr null check, can this condition let a null shared_ptr pass?

Tags: c++, null, shared-ptr, disassembly

I'm investigating a dump, caused by the following piece of code:

```
shared_ptr<Type_Definition> entry = function_result();

if (entry != nullptr) {
  if (launch_other_function(entry, value, timestamp)) { // <= here it crashes
    ...
```

When putting the three variables in the Watch-window (putting the cursor on the crashing line), I see:

- valid values for `timestamp` and `value`
- for `entry` : `Cannot obtain value of the local variable or argument because it is not available at this instruction pointer, possibly because it has been optimized away.`

I believe that `function_result()` gives a null-pointer, and that the `null-pointer` check for `entry` is not able to recognise it, lets it pass and hence, results in an access violation (for your information, the exception message states `Access violation executing location 0x00000000.`).

My question is not : how can I check for a null-pointer (I know this can be done using `if (entry)`), but: am I correct that this check might allow a `±nullish shared pointer` (sorry, I don't know how to formulate it correctly) to pass the condition?

Does anybody have an idea?

For your information: hereby the declaration of `launch_other_function()`:

```
bool launch_other_function(const shared_ptr<Type_Definition>& entry, double value, DATE timestamp){
...
}
```

In the Disassembly window, I see the following lines of code (I hope it makes sense):

```
0127AA32 85 C0                test        eax,eax  
0127AA34 0F 84 3C 01 00 00    je          0127AB76  
0127AA3A 8B 8D 9C FE FF FF    mov         ecx,dword ptr [ebp-164h]  
0127AA40 FF 15 E4 AF 31 00    call        dword ptr ds:[31AFE4h]  
0127AA46 85 C0                test        eax,eax  
0127AA48 0F 84 AC 00 00 00    je          0127AAFA  
0127AA4E 8B 85 9C FE FF FF    mov         eax,dword ptr [ebp-164h]  
0127AA54 8B B8 80 00 00 00    mov         edi,dword ptr [eax+80h]  
0127AA5A DD 45 0C             fld         qword ptr [ebp+0Ch]  
0127AA5D 83 EC 08             sub         esp,8  
0127AA60 DD 1C 24             fstp        qword ptr [esp]  
0127AA63 C7 85 8C FE FF FF 78 15 4C 00 mov         dword ptr [ebp-174h],4C1578h  
0127AA6D 89 A5 90 FE FF FF    mov         dword ptr [ebp-170h],esp  
0127AA73 C7 85 94 FE FF FF 87 AA 27 01 mov         dword ptr [ebp-16Ch],127AA87h  
0127AA7D C6 46 08 00          mov         byte ptr [esi+8],0  
0127AA81 FF 15 74 17 4C 00    call        dword ptr ds:[4C1774h]  
0127AA87 83 C4 08             add         esp,8  
0127AA8A C6 46 08 01          mov         byte ptr [esi+8],1  
0127AA8E 83 3D 40 D0 01 69 00 cmp         dword ptr ds:[6901D040h],0  
0127AA95 74 09                je          0127AAA0  
0127AA97 50                   push        eax  
0127AA98 52                   push        edx  
0127AA99 E8 82 D9 8B 67       call        68B38420  
0127AA9E 5A                   pop         edx  
0127AA9F 58                   pop         eax
```

Oh, I forgot: the program in multi-threaded indeed.

About adding debugging info, I'm afraid there's not much to add, as can be seen in following excerpt of the `modules` tab (for both cases (I guess, managed an native code), the symbols are loaded already):

```
<Product_Name>.exe  <Product_Name>.exe  C:\<Product_Name>.exe   N/A Yes Symbols loaded. C:\Dump_Analyse\<Product_Name>.pdb\5BEA8C97EB644ED2B06B9AFE450EF23E1\<Product_Name>.pdb 2   9.05.1638.3292  25/10/2017 15:02    01050000-011DC000   <Product_Name>.exe_180423_041510.dmp        
<Product_Name>.exe  <Product_Name>.exe  C:\<Product_Name>.exe   Yes No  Symbols loaded. C:\Dump_Analyse\<Product_Name>.pdb\5BEA8C97EB644ED2B06B9AFE450EF23E1\<Product_Name>.pdb 14  9.05.1638.3292  25/10/2017 15:02    01050000-011DC000   <Product_Name>.exe_180423_041510.dmp    [1] <Product_Name>.exe
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is a "nullish shared pointer" and why do you believe that `if (entry != nullptr)` doesn't work? Also what are all these other variables and functions and how did you exclude them to be the cause of the issue?

Comment: @YSC: I've added the declaration of `launch_other_function()` to the question.

Comment: @UnholySheep: I'm sorry for the bad terminology, but as I'm doubting about the checking of the pointer, I didn't know how to formulate my request.

Comment: It would help if you could [add the debug info](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/specify-symbol-dot-pdb-and-source-files-in-the-visual-studio-debugger) to the assembly listing.

Comment: @YSC: I'm sorry, but I don't know what you mean: in the disassembly window, I've checked "Show code bytes", "Show address", "Show source code", "Show symbol names" and "Show line numbers", there aren't more checkboxes about things to show. How can I add the mentioned debug info to the assembly listing?

Comment: Follow the link .........................^

Comment: @YSC: sorry, but the symbols seem to be loaded already. What exactly do you expect to see?

Comment: What makes you think `nullptr` is getting through despite the check? https://ideone.com/Gnzqdf <-- works

Comment: @KillzoneKid: As you can see, the value of `entry` is calculated using `function_result()`, then it passes the null-pointer check but when asking its value, it is mentioned to be optimised away (despite the other two parameters of the other functions) and an access violation, referring to memory address 0x0...0, is thrown. Do you believe there is another explanation for this access violation?

Comment: About `launch_other_function`: is it a free function? A non-srtatic member function? etc. What is the value of `this` just before the program crashes?

Comment: @YSC: I've added the declaration of the function in the question. About the value of `this`: the watch-window gives `<Unable to read memory>` as a result.